# Possible to configure IntelliJ to invoke SmartType code completion without using a shortcut?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Right now IntelliJ instantly pops-up a box with suggestions for code completion as I am typing. However the suggestions are just "basic", and not as "smart" as when I use the (Ctrl+Shift+Space) shortcut to invoke SmartType completion. Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to automatically invoke SmartType completion as I type?

Comment: There is no such setting. Note that this might not be a good idea. The list of smart type completion suggestions is smaller than the list of regular suggestions and does not include keywords and identifiers that you might need if you're retrieving a value of the expected type via a chained method call, array access or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. No one asked for it, it provides only a few variants, it may suggest not what you want to write automatically and will produce unexpected results when completing automatically on space and dot.

Basic automatic completion is already designed to include smart variants at the top where possible.

Comment: Users interested in more details can refer to the [discussion here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6716).